# NodeRed populate node form from msg payload from previous node output

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-red

I have a couple custom nodes that reach out to a webservice to pull data with atomic ids. I want to pull in all items (array of json payloads) with one node, add to the msg payload and use that payload .on("input") to populate the configuration form within the html of the second node.

```
module.export = (RED) => {
    let data = [];
    const getAllNode = () => {
       // promised data returned 
       data = service.getAllData(config);
       let node = this;
        RED.nodes.createNode(node, config);

        node.on('input', (msg) => {
             // simple pseudo but this part works fine
             msg.payload = data;

             node.send(msg);
        })
    }

    RED.nodes.registerType("get-all", getAllNode);
}
```

data getting set against the msg.payload property something like this

```
[
     { first: "Bob", last: "Smith", age: 45, id: 241 },
     { first: "Karen", last: "NotThatKaren", age: 32, id: 112 },
     { first: "Latisha", last: "Rhodes", age: 41, id: 742 }
]
```

in the next node I would like to set up the html (if possible) that would display a select box of the just the first name based on the msg payload coming into it.....is this possible to dynamically change the html when the .on("input") receives the msg?

```
<script type="text/html" data-template-name="some-binding">
    template something here based on a template/data binding??
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can not change the displayed settings based on the input from a preceeding node.

Also each nodes configuration should be independent of any other nodes, with the exception that they can share config nodes. A node should not need to know anything about what nodes preceed/postceed in the flow (things like http-in/http-out get round this by attaching the response object to the `msg`)

You have to understand that the 2 parts (HTML, JS) of the node are totally independent. The HTML part runs in the browser,the JS part runs on the backend. The backend has no access to the HTML part.

Also worth remembering that if you start with a blank canvas and add your fist node, then the second and wire them together, there will be NO messages passing between them until you hit deploy, so there would be no way for the first node to populate the second.

While you can choose to override the settings entered in the HTML with data attached to the message, there is no way to persist this data into the flow's saved state.

If the configuration of your node depends on some backend system then you can make HTTP requests from within the HTML section to request that data for each node, you can either make these in the `onEditPrepare` callback or you can attach event handlers to items in the HTML form to do this on demand, e.g. to buttons. If needed you can add HTTP routes to your JS file that can be called from the HTTP to get round Cross Site Access issues. See things like the Serial Port core node for an example.

Comment: makes sense. appreciate it.